# Cor RGB no Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, microsoft, background-color

Como consigo ter mais cores para o fundo do meu formulário? Tenho uma cor em RGB e não sei como colocá-la além das cores já oferecidas no Visual Studio 2017. Já tentei pesquisar na internet e não achei nada

> [image: Opções oferecidas]

Comment: é no Personalizar, lá você cria!

Comment: Como? Por lá só vi mais opções de cores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No arquivo `Form1.cs`(nome do seu formulário) dentro de `public Form1()`(nome do seu formulário) insira o seguinte código:

```
this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 232, 232); //os 3 parâmetros são os valores RGB
```

Com isso você pode alterar a cor do seu formulário de forma programável. Se quiser uma [referência via Youtube aqui está](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFQ_MOiwwFg).

Comment: Muito obrigado! Para mudar o fundo da ferramenta 'panel' usa-se o mesmo comando?

Comment: Você precisa acessar o objeto Panel(através do seu nome, assim como fiz com só que ao invés de `this` você coloca o nome da variável do objeto), mas sim é a mesma lógica.

Answer (score 0):

Além da resposta para que possa mudar o valor `RGB` pelo caminho de programação, naquela caixa que você abriu é só digitar o `RGB` separado por `;` que automaticamente é gerado, exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Todos os componentes que tiverem configuração de cores também pode ser utilizado a mesma estratégia.

Só por curiosidade o código gerado por baixo é :

```
this
     .textBox1
     .ForeColor = System
        .Drawing
        .Color
        .FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(100)))), ((int)(((byte)(253)))), ((int)(((byte)(80)))));
```

Comment: Perfeito Virgilio, Muito obrigado! <3